# Stablizer of action in kernel of character

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Set 
$$G^*=\{\chi:G\to \mathbb{C}\mid \chi \text{ is homomorphism}\}.$$

Let $X$ be set, assume that $G$ acts on $X$. For $x \in X$, 
I would like to compute
$$\#\{\chi \in G^*\mid \text{Stab}_G(x)\subseteq \ker \chi\}.$$
How one could do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it really important to mention the action? Can't we ask this question for any subgroup $H<G$?

Comment: ${\rm Stab}_G(x) \in {\rm ker} \chi$ doesn't make sense. Do you mean ${\rm Stab}_G(x) \le {\rm ker} \chi$ (or perhaps ${\rm Stab}_G(x) = {\rm ker} \chi$)?

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for correction. I fixed it.

Comment: Isn't the answer just the number of characters of $G/{\rm Stab}_G(x)$, which is $|G|/|{\rm Stab}_G(x)|$?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I am interesting in the method in general, so if you could provide an example that would be Ok. indeed I am interesting in examples of free action

Comment: @DerekHolt many thanks for your reply, can you please explain more if possible?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H<G$ be any subgroup, and look for $\sharp\{\chi\in G^*|H<\ker\chi\}$. Since the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup, our number is equal to $\sharp\{\chi\in G^*|\overline{H}<\ker\chi\}$, where $\overline{H}$ is the normal closure. This is just the number of homomorphisms $\varphi:G/\overline{H}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain more? I still do not understand how you got this result.

Comment: It is a quite useful fact that there is a bijection between $\{\varphi:A\to B|C<\ker\varphi\}$ and $\{\varphi:A/C\to B\}$. Try to prove it, it's an important basic exercise.